# Unity Editor GUI text becoming misaligned

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, editor

I'm currently working on my editor extension and decided to add a custom button using an image instead, which was then put on the same row as a text field using a horizontal layout group

Unfortunately, the textfield stops being aligned to the centre.

[image]

Here is the code in question with the problem

```
//Displays absolute root path
EditorGUILayout.SelectableLabel("Root Directory: " + RootPath, EditorStyles.miniLabel, GUILayout.MaxHeight(16));

//Creates BuildPath
DesiredPathType = (PathType)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup(new GUIContent("Path Type"), DesiredPathType);

//BuildName TextField
BuildName = EditorGUILayout.TextField(new GUIContent("Build Name"), BuildName);

//OutputPath directory selector
GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
GUIStyle Style = EditorStyles.textField;
Style.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;
OutputPath = EditorGUILayout.TextField(new GUIContent("Output Path"), OutputPath, Style);

Style = GUIStyle.none;
Style.padding = new RectOffset(0, 0, 2, 0);
GUILayout.Button(new GUIContent(FolderIcon), Style, GUILayout.MaxHeight(16), GUILayout.MaxWidth(19));

GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

//SubFolders toggle
Subfolders = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(new GUIContent("Subfolder per Platform"), Subfolders);
```

Specifically, this part

```
//OutputPath directory selector
GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
GUIStyle Style = EditorStyles.textField;
Style.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;
OutputPath = EditorGUILayout.TextField(new GUIContent("Output Path"), OutputPath, Style);

Style = GUIStyle.none;
Style.padding = new RectOffset(0, 0, 2, 0);
GUILayout.Button(new GUIContent(FolderIcon), Style, GUILayout.MaxHeight(16), GUILayout.MaxWidth(19));
```

GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

FolderIcon image

[image]

Comment: the textfield stops being aligned to the centre? What's the expected appearence? Maybe you can show us a sketch.

Comment: Added issue on the left, desired on the right

Comment: I still cannot figure out the issue. The only difference between left and right is the existense of `FolderIcon`.

Comment: Zoom in and look closely; on the right Output Path textfield is perfectly centred between the GUI elements above and below it whereas on the left the whole thing is slightly too low

Comment: Oh, I see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (UI-only):

```
//dummy local variables
string RootPath = null;
PathType DesiredPathType = PathType.Abs;
string BuildName = "";
string OutputPath = "";
bool Subfolders = false;

//Displays absolute root path
EditorGUILayout.SelectableLabel("Root Directory: " + RootPath, EditorStyles.miniLabel, GUILayout.MaxHeight(16));

//Creates BuildPath
EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Path Type", DesiredPathType);

//BuildName TextField
BuildName = EditorGUILayout.TextField(new GUIContent("Build Name"), BuildName);

//OutputPath directory selector
GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
GUIStyle Style = EditorStyles.textField;
Style.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;
OutputPath = EditorGUILayout.TextField(new GUIContent("Output Path"), OutputPath, Style);

GUILayout.Button(new GUIContent("O"), EditorStyles.label, GUILayout.MaxHeight(16), GUILayout.MaxWidth(19));

GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

//SubFolders toggle
Subfolders = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(new GUIContent("Subfolder per Platform"), Subfolders);
```

It was `GUIStyle.none` that caused the issue. The code above just uses `EditorStyles.label` instead. But I don't know why it works. You may dig into decompiled code of `EditorGUILayout.Textfield` to find out the reason.

And you are making a mistake that your code modifies `EditorStyles.textField` directly. This will change the style of all `TextField`. Instead, you should call [`new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.textField)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIStyle-ctor.html) to create a new `GUIStyle` object.

Comment: Seems to work more or less. Image ends up too small for my liking but I'll likely be able to work around that